# Deleting EGL Opengles 2.0 properly

Tags: c++, memory, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I've written a program that creates a window on WINCE and uses EGL to create the drawing surface and context. When this program quits, I have the following clean up routine:

```
eglMakeCurrent(m_eglDisplay,EGL_NO_SURFACE,EGL_NO_SURFACE,m_eglContext);
eglDestroyContext(m_eglDisplay,m_eglContext);       
glDeleteProgram(m_eglProgramObject);
glReleaseShaderCompiler();

delete m_eglDisplay;
delete m_eglSurface;
delete m_eglContext;
delete m_eglConfig;
```

If I don't restart the target system, eventually the opening and closing of this program causes this following line to fail:

```
m_eglContext = eglCreateContext(m_eglDisplay,m_eglConfig,EGL_NO_CONTEXT,arrContextAttrib);
```

With EGL error 12291 which apparently means EGL_BAD_ALLOC. I assume there's some memory related to EGL that isn't being deleted properly every time the program exits but don't know what this could possibly be. Any suggestions?

Comment: A proper implementation should clean up all OpenGL related resources when a program exits. That being said, are you destroying the surface as well? Might be worth a try if you're not doing that already. Also, your sequence above is invalid. The `glDelete*()` calls need to be made as long as you still have a valid current context.

Comment: @RetoKoradi thanks for your advice. I have looked through the cheat sheets for both EGL and Opengles 2.0 and made amends to the code to include in the deconstructor:

`glDeleteProgram(m_eglProgramObject);
glReleaseShaderCompiler();
eglTerminate(m_eglDisplay);
eglMakeCurrent(m_eglDisplay,EGL_NO_SURFACE,EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT );
eglDestroySurface(m_eglDisplay,m_eglSurface);
eglDestroyContext(m_eglDisplay,m_eglContext);
eglReleaseThread();`

Comment: But the same result happens. Eventually there's a bad memory alloc for EGL :/ May you be kind enough to point out what the proper sequence of glDelete calls it should be?

Answer (score 2):

To properly release your EGL and OpenGL 2.0 resources properly you have to make do following;

```
glDeleteProgram(m_eglProgramObject);
```

**Delete any other GL resources created. For example textures, framebuffer, vertexbuffer, pixelbuffers etc**

After this you have to do a eglmakecurrent with null surfaces and context. This will de-associate your EGLContext with the current thread (TLS)

```
eglMakeCurrent(m_eglDisplay,EGL_NO_SURFACE,EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT );
```

After this you have to release all the EGLResources created:

```
eglDestroySurface(m_eglDisplay,m_eglSurface); 
eglDestroyContext(m_eglDisplay,m_eglContext);
```

In the end do the eglTerminate:

```
eglTerminate(m_eglDisplay);
```

If you have also created any platform window object, For example XDisplay for X11, wl_display for Wayland or AWindow for Android. You have to delete/destroy that also.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Come to think of it I'm not releasing the device context when I create the window. Gonna try that.